# How to make ajax webservice calls from windows phone 8 html5 application?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a sample windows phone 8 application built using jquery mobile and phonegap, When i run the application on browser it works fine with no issues .
The problem is when i run the application from emulator or device its not able make ajax webservice calls , Can i please know is their any setting i should enable to access webservice calls from emulator or device

Sample Code:

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: URL + "Sample.aspx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        isLocal: true,
        success: function (all) {
            alert("hi2");
            store.set('sampleData', data);    
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
```

Comment: `console.log($.support.ajax);` if it returns _false_, then device doesn't support Ajax.

Comment: In phonegap config.xml. do you have <access origin=".*"/>? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904320/consuming-asp-net-web-service-from-phonegap. Also, sample.aspx is neither a web service, nor a PageMethod, have you considered using a standard asmx web service for all your ajax needs?

Comment: @ezanker : The same application is working fine in android device, aspx is just returning json data